# Eclipse IDE java equivalent of PHP include?

Tags: java, php, eclipse, include, equivalent

I've been digging around but can't find anything useful.

I'm working on an Android App.

Basically I have a package and there are three java files in it so far; my main screen page, a settings page and what I have called my 'subs.java' where I am putting useful functions, routines.

What I am trying to do is create this 'subs.java' file where routines that get used in more than one place can be stored.

So I have my main app page and I have a settings page. Both of these 'pages' need to use these common functions.

So I was going to put them in my 'subs.java' so I don't end up doubling up code.

Where I am stuck is now I have this subs.java file how do I link to it ?

In PHP if I want to use another file I just **include** it and I have access to all it's functions.

I suppose I am trying to build up a library, but Java is new to me.

How then would I do this in Eclipse/Java please ?

Here's my subs file, with some useful functions that I found else where :

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Subs extends Activity {

    // Read settings
    public String ReadSettings(Context context){
        FileInputStream fIn = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;

        char[] inputBuffer = new char[255];
        String data = null;

        try {
            fIn = openFileInput("settings.dat");      

            isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
            isr.read(inputBuffer);
            data = new String(inputBuffer);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Settings read",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {      
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Settings not read",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                isr.close();
                fIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

 // Save settings
    public void WriteSettings(Context context, String data){
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

        try {
              fOut = openFileOutput("settings.dat",MODE_PRIVATE);      
              osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
              osw.write(data);
              osw.flush();
              Toast.makeText(context, "Settings saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {      
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Settings not saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                osw.close();
                fOut.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to PHP's `include` in Java is `import`. Read more about using [`import` and `package` in Java](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a project as a package then any class using that package can access any other ones. So if you had `SomeFileA.java` and it uses package `com.something.me`, and `SomeFileB.java` that uses package `com.something.me` then they can reference each other. Typically Eclipse will auto-add any imports if you just flat out write `SomeFileB b = new SomeFileB();` inside SomeFileA. If not you can just do use

```
import com.something.me.SomeFileB;
```

Comment: This seems promising.   I added : import com.example.helloandroid.Subs; But when I use the functions within Subs it has a red line under it saying 'cannot be resolved....'

Comment: I added my subs file to my post above.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `import` statement to import your subs class. Then you can refer to any function in the subs class as `subs.functionName()`

If subs.java is in the same folder as your other java files, you can simply type `import subs`.

Read more about packages and imports at http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter05/packagesImport.html

Answer (score 0):

What about "import" ? You can import a simple class, not only a library...

Put your common routines as static methods in a class ("MyAppHelper" for example), and call them in your "screens" :

```
MyAppHelper.function1(...)
```